# Entity Framework Core | dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold | Could not load assembly of project

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, scaffolding

I want to scaffold a SQL Server and output to a project.

I have a solution with 2 projects:

- Project 1: "Scaffolder" .NET 6.0
- Project 2: "Scaffolded" .NET Standard 2.1

They both have these dependencies

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.0
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 5.0.0
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 5.0.0

I want the scaffolded data in project `Scaffolded`.

In the solution folder I run this command:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "<MyConnectionString>" 
       Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 
       --startup-project Scaffolder --project Scaffolded --output-dir Models --force
```

I get this output:

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
```

> Could not load assembly 'Scaffolded'. Ensure it is referenced by the startup project 'Scaffolder'

Why do I get this error?

I run Entity Framework Core .NET Command-line Tools 5.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use EF Core Power Tools - but upgrade to EF Core 6, EF Core 5 is no longer supported.